# Postgresql overlapping date ranges and summing results

Tags: postgresql, date, join, date-range

I am trying to link a table of contracts to a list of transactions in order to see if there has been any overspend, however, the data doesn't have an effective, unique shared key.

Here's an example of my contracts table:

```
| buyer_id | supplier_id | start_date | end_date   | contract_value  |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-01-01 | 2017-01-01 | 240000          |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-01 | 6000            |
| buyer_a  | supplier_b  | 2015-01-01 | 2015-12-31 | 100000          |
| buyer_a  | supplier_b  | 2017-01-01 | 2017-12-31 | 100000          |
```

Here's an example of my spending table:

```
| buyer_id | supplier_id | month      | trans_value    |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-01-01 | 1230.12        |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-02-01 | 1735.98        |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-03-01 | 2242.02        |
```

Because the contract dates overlap (e.g the contracts with supplier_a), I can't just link all the transactions for each month of each contract as this would mean that I'm double counting transactions during the period of overlap.

Equally, I can't use max() and min() because then any transactions occurring in the period between contracts (e.g. those with supplier_b) are going to be included.

As far as I can tell the best way to link these tables is to roll up my contracts table into a view so that it looks something like this...

```
| buyer_id | supplier_id | month      | value |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-01-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-02-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-03-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-04-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-05-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-06-01 | 10000 |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-07-01 | 10000 |
```

As long as the values for each month are a summed share of the contract,  it is easy to link the transactions on a triple column unique of `buyer_id`, `supplier_id` and `month`, and I can then identify any overspend.

The problem is that I can't even begin to work out how to build the new view. I feel like I should be able to use a sub-query to 'unpack' the date range into a list of months and then something like sum(case()) but I'm out of my depth.

ps. I don't have any control over how this data is published, so I can't improve the data at source.

Edit: I'd like to be able to create an output like this which I can then put in a chart to show overspend:

```
| buyer_id | supplier_id | month      | monthly_con_val | trans_value |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-01-01 | 10000           | 34000       |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-02-01 | 10000           | 10000       |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-03-01 | 50000           | 8000        |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-04-01 | 50000           | 14000       |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-05-01 | 50000           | 4000        |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-06-01 | 10000           | 3000        |
| buyer_a  | supplier_a  | 2015-07-01 | 10000           | 3000        |
```

Comment: Could you provide the example of result that you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
with
  -- Sample data
  contracts(bs_id, start_date, end_date, contract_value) as (values
    (1, '2015-01-01'::date, '2017-01-01'::date, 240000),
    (1, '2016-01-01'::date, '2016-06-01'::date, 6000)),
  spending(bs_id, month, trans_value) as (values
    (1, '2015-01-01'::date, 1230.12),
    (1, '2015-02-01'::date, 1735.98),
    (1, '2016-05-01'::date, 5689.01)),
  -- End of sample data
  contracts_monthly as (
    select
      bs_id,
      month::date,
      sum(
        contract_value / (
          (extract(year from end_date)*12 + extract(month from end_date)) - 
          (extract(year from start_date)*12 + extract(month from start_date)))) as monthly_con_val
    from contracts, generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 month') as month
    group by bs_id, month
    order by bs_id, month)
select
  *
from
  contracts_monthly left join spending using (bs_id, month);
```

To make the example more compact, I had merge the columns `buyer_id | supplier_id` into single column `bs_id`.

[About `generate_series()` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html)